# Using : and :: in C++ without confusing

Tags: c++, class, syntax, ownership

1. Both : and :: punctuations in C++ can bind ownership of function within class, or subclass within base class. But it's not fully clear when to use each in general, and which to put in header and which in cpp source files (if this is a matter of personal flavor, please tell more common convention). Concise example would be appreciable so much!
2. Please correct me if I am wrong or not precise enough, and list other cases if I missed some for using : and ::
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Scope operator and introducing the inheritance type list for a class are completely orthogonal situations.

Comment: I don't see the problem. When you accidentally use one instead of the other, then you will almost surely get a compiler error in any imaginable circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

`bind` is not the best word to use for this.
`::` *scopes* functions and so on.

For example `std::cout` says there is something called `cout` in a scope (namespace, class...) called `std`.

`:` does not do this and can be used in a variety of ways.

It can follow an access specifier, for example `public:`.

It is also part of the ternary conditional `x ? y : z`